# ns3 packet failed

Tags: c++, ns-3

In my simulation I send many packets succefully but at some point I get this error:

```
assert failed. cond="m_nBytes >= packet->GetSize ()
```

All packets have the same size and I also wait for the queue of the NetDevice to be empty before sending the next one. Does anyone know why this might be happening?

Thanks